# C# Function Error

Tags: c#, function

As I'm new to C# I'm trying to make a basic console based calculator.  It's getting one error though.  Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionBased_Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        public void menu()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("-=Calculator=-\n");
            Console.WriteLine("(1.) Addition");
            Console.WriteLine("(2.) Subtraction");
            Console.WriteLine("(3.) Multiplication");
            Console.WriteLine("(4.) Division");
            Console.WriteLine("(5.) Help");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
            if (answer == "1")
            {
                addition();
            }
            else
            {
                if (answer == "2")
                {
                    subtraction();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (answer == "3")
                    {
                        multiplication();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (answer == "4")
                        {
                            division();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (answer == "5")
                            {
                                help();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                                menu();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void addition()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-=Addition=-\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Number 1:");
            int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("-=Addition=-\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Number 2:");
            int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("-=Addition=-\n");
            int sum = num1 + num2;
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            Console.ReadKey();
            menu();
        }
        public void subtraction()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-=Subtraction=-\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Number 1:");
            int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("-=Subtraction=-\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Number 2:");
            int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("-=Subtraction=-\n");
            int sum = num1 - num2;
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            Console.ReadKey();
            menu();
        }
        public void multiplication()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-=Multiplication=-\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Number 1:");
            int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("-=Multiplication=-\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Number 2:");
            int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("-=Multiplication=-\n");
            int sum = num1 * num2;
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            Console.ReadKey();
            menu();
        }
        public void division()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-=Division=-\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Number 1:");
            int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("-=Division=-\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Number 2:");
            int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("-=Division=-\n");
            int sum = num1 / num2;
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
            Console.ReadKey();
            menu();
        }
        public void help()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-=Help=-\n");
            Console.WriteLine("If you got compiled this by yourself you don't need help.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            menu();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            menu();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get every time I try to run it (I'm using VS Express 2013) I get this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'FunctionBased_Calculator.Program.menu()'

It's on line 133.  I think it might have something to do with using menu() inside static void main.  If anyone could help me that'd be great!

Answer (score 2):

`menu()` needs to be declared as `static`, along with it's entire call hierarchy:

```
public static void menu()
```

The compiler leaves no room for error. When accessing a`static` method that's declared on the *type*, not the instance, you need to make sure any field or method called from it is static as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a static to all your methods declaration like

```
public static void menu()
{
      ......
```

From static methods you can only call static methods o invoke new instance.